# Store Sql Server Compact database within a zip file. Is this possible?

Tags: zip, sql-server-ce

Can I place a sql server compact database within a zip file and then use it as a normal stand alone database file?

The reason I ask is that there are a number of files that I want to keep together including the database for an application that I have and it would make it easier to move a single zip file to another pc rather than have a directory of files.

Comment: Nope. Not unless you want to write your own provider (very non trivial). Nothing wrong with a folder of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to unzip it before you can use it in your application.  But then, that's true of the other files in your zip also.

Comment: It is not exactly so. It's possible to create a virtual storage card on Windows CE by writing a special DLL (similar to kernel-mode driver in Windows). This storage card becomes visible to all processes as part of the filesystem.

Comment: Yeah, and I can drive my car backwards to work, too.  Doesn't mean it's a good idea.